# Images not saved in desired folder after taking a screenshot using Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to save a screenshot, taken using Webdriver. I am using a string to store the Filepath. But I am not able to save the screenshot in desired folder. Instead, the desired path gets appended in the name of the file that I'm trying to save.

```
public void takeScreenshot(String obj) throws IOException{

 driver= new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 baseUrl="http://northeastindiaholidays.com";
 driver.get(baseUrl);

 String Filepath="D:\\Selenium_sc";
 File SrcFile=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
 FileUtils.copy(SrcFile,new File(Filepath + obj+""+ getTimeStampValue() + ".png")
}
```

The screenshot is taken, but Selenium_Sc gets appended in the Filename like "Selenium_Sc..imagename". How I can save this to the specified folder. Is there a problem taking the file path as a String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is that you are missing the path separators, as @Deepak pointed out.

What I can add is that I would suggest to use [java.nio.Path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [java.nio.Paths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) when manipulating paths.

For joining paths, like in your case, you can leverage Paths.get.
E.g.:

```
String screenshotsDir = "D:\\Selenium_sc";
String filename = obj+"_"+ getTimeStampValue() + ".png";
Path screenshotPath = Paths.get(screenshotsDir, filename);
File SrcFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, screenshotPath.toFile())
```

Notice the convenience method Path#toFile (there is also the opposite: File#toPath)

PS: only for JDK>=7

Answer (score 0):

I used following function & snap is stored in desired folder -

```
public void takeScreenshot(String obj) throws IOException{
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
 Timestamp t = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
 String dateNow = t.toString().replace(":","_");
 driver= new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 baseUrl="http://northeastindiaholidays.com";
 driver.get(baseUrl);
 File SrcFile=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
 FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile,new File("D:\\Selenium_sc\\"+dateNow+".png"));
}
```

}

You can add String obj parameter you are passing to method in last line. Just make sure path separators("\") are correct. E.G. -

```
 FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile,new File("D:\\Selenium_sc\\"+obj+"\\"+dateNow+".png"));
```